# Send Direct Message With Media(photo) Twitter API using PHP

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using "themattharris" OAUTH library for reading & sending Tweets as well as Direct Messages, I am able to send

1. New Tweets
2. Reply on Tweets
3. Reply on Tweets with Media

I used the Twitter status update API call given below

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json (for Tweets without media)
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json (for Tweets with media)
```

In response I am able to get the `Tweet Object(json_encoded)`, through which I can save in my database

When I try the same for `Direct Message`(preceding "D" before twitter username), the reply went successfully to `Twitter` Website & I am able to see the direct message, but in `RESPONSE` from `Twitter` it is returning the last `Tweet Object` instead of the `Message Object`?

I also looked at `twitter direct message API`

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json
```

but it is not having parameter for media upload.

Can Anyone Help me with this?

**Basically I want to send direct message with media & in RESPONSE I should get the DIRECT MESSAGE OBJECT not the LAST TWEET OBJECT.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way late, but the answer is you *can't* send a direct message with media:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/uploading-images-in-dms/12317